# How does Java ServerSocket get a new socket bound to the same local port after accept the client?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am confused about Socket and ServerSocket port usages. [Oracle's java tutorial about sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/definition.html) says the following :

> ***What Is a Socket?***
>
> Normally, a server runs on a specific computer and has a socket that is bound to a specific port number. The server just waits, listening to the socket for a client to make a connection request.
>   On the client-side: The client knows the hostname of the machine on which the server is running and the port number on which the server is listening. To make a connection request, the client tries to rendezvous with the server on the server's machine and port. The client also needs to identify itself to the server so it binds to a local port number that it will use during this connection. This is usually assigned by the system.
>
> If everything goes well, the server accepts the connection. **Upon
>   acceptance, the server gets a new socket bound to the same local port**
>   and also has its remote endpoint set to the address and port of the
>   client. It needs a new socket so that it can continue to listen to the
>   original socket for connection requests while tending to the needs of
>   the connected client.
>
> On the client side, if the connection is accepted, a socket is successfully created and the client can use the socket to communicate with the server.
>   The client and server can now communicate by writing to or reading from their sockets.

I tried the following code to test. But it throws an exception.

```java
try {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);

    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

    // This prints 8080
    System.out.println("Local port of accepted socket : " + socket.getLocalPort());  

    // But this throws java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind 
    Socket myClientSocket = new Socket("www.google.com", 80, null, 8080);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My question is obvious. While the socket returned from `serverSocket.accept()` can use the same local port (`8080`) why the socket that I created cannot use it?

Comment: Because that's the way they designed it. Please be clear about what you are quoting.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple, the listening TCP socket is already explicitly bound to the port, so you can't explicitly bind a second TCP socket to the same port (unless both sockets are also explicitly bound to different IP addresses, not including INADDR_ANY).

The accepted sockets don't go through an explicit 'bind' process. They acquire their local IP address and port automagically, as does an outbound socket if you connect it without binding.

Answer (score -1):

Your server and client are using the same local port to communicate. When you created the server socket you "said" it must listening on 8080 port. That´s ok. Any one that wants to communicate with your server socket must use such port.

But, right below you are creating a client socket that connects to google site using the port 80 (google is listening on that port) and, in the last argument, you are saying that this socket must use also the local port 8080 to establish the connection. Only one connection can use a port at a time, that´s why you are getting java.net.BindException, both server and client connections are using 8080.

My suggestion ... take the last two arguments from you socket client constructor, or change you local client port (always get a high number to avoid the same problem with other process):

```
Socket myClientSocket = new Socket("www.google.com", 80);
```

or

```
Socket myClientSocket = new Socket("www.google.com", 80, null, 58080);
```

Comment: The OP is asking *why* this happens, when a port created with the server `accept` is allowed to have a local port of `8080`.

Comment: I think I've answered it when I said: "Only one process can use a port at a time, that´s why you are getting java.net.BindException." He is using 8080 local port for both server and client (inbound and outbound)

Comment: @RaphaelMoita All this code is running in the same process. You haven't answered the question.

Comment: @RaphaelMoita Your edit is no improvement. 'Only one connection can use a port at a time' is manifestly false. You can have thousands of inbound connections on the same local port.

Comment: Agree that the word "process" was wrong. Hope the edition I've done helps to clarify what I meant. "Only one connection can use a port at a time, that´s why you are getting java.net.BindException, both server and client connections are using 8080."

Comment: Completely changing the basis of your answer is hardly 'clarifying what you meant', and it's still wrong.

Comment: In a low level ... Only one connection can be established at a time. Whats happens is that socket servers dispatch (not sure if it is the best word to use here) immediately to a higher internal port and releases the external port (in this case 8080) to receive the next connection.

Comment: Well, as the OP shows, the "internal" socket has the port 8080 as its internal port. That's still the port that the packets are going to be sent to.

Comment: @RaphaelMoita Multiple inbound connections will all use the  same local port at the server. ***This is what the question is about,*** and it is also clearly (and correctly) stated in the Oracle documentation quoted by the OP. Have a look at a `netstat` display on a server. Your claim about 'dispatch[ing] internally to a higher port and releas[ing] the external port' is complete and utter garbage.